# Is it possible to exploit `-i lo -j ACCEPT` in iptables?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables, internet-security

Most of iptable setups contain `INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT` rule. Without it it's quite difficult to connect to any locally hosted stuff. However what is not entirely clear to me - is locally running process absolutely the only way to get caught by this line? I mean can it be exploited by something like delivery of crafted packet with src ip 127.0.0.1, dst 127.0.0.1 when ip forwarding is enabled on some interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you would use two more lines as show below then events you described would be blocked:

```
-A INPUT -4 ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT
-A INPUT -6 ! -i lo -d ::1/128 -j REJECT
-A INPUT      -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Given that rules are processed in order, you'd need to put the first rule after the other two. Right now, the last two will never be reached.

Comment: You right, I reordered rules in my answer to reflect @user2313067 comment